# Returning each file path into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a upload function in my controller that takes multiple file uploads.  So far it uploads the files to the directory but I want to capture each one into an `array`.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is the code

```
$files = Request::file('document');

        foreach($files as $file) {
            $rules = array(
               'file' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc,docx,rtf|max:20000'
            );
            $validator = \Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
            if($validator->passes()){

                $destinationPath = '/public/uploads/';
                $mime_type = $file->getMimeType();
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filename = str_random(12) . '.' . $extension;  
                $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

            } else {
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'We only accept png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc,rtf.'); // add error here.
            }
        }
```

When validator passes it processes each one but when I add a variable like `$path = $upload_success;`  it obviously just takes the last one processed.  How can I capture an array of all the file paths processed into `$path`?

Comment: If `$file->move()` returns the final path to the file then: `$paths[] = $upload_success;`. No?

Comment: yes, $filename is actually the path I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `foreach`, create an array `$paths = [];`

After the `$upload_success` var is created, add it to the array.  `$paths[] = $upload_success;`

Now `$paths` will be an array of all your paths.

Comment: Thankyou for the solution!  I have a nice array to loop in another function now :)